# Finding wrong duplicate data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi I recently started working as a software engineer so this question might be too noob but please bear with me.

I have three columns, let's say fruit, color, taste.

Fruit can have many colors and tastes. But one fruit which has a specific color should have a same taste. For example, (apple, red) should have only one taste.
(apple, red, sour) and (apple, red, sweet) can't exist together.

The problem I have is my table contains multiple duplicate tastes with same fruit and color. I have tried different joins but got wrong results.

Sorry for such an awful description but if anyone could understand and help me I would really appreciate.

Comment: Could you please post an example of your tables and the queries you have tried?

Comment: HI and welcome to SO. The answer you seek can be found here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Example question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50008226/6327676

Comment: "I have tried different joins".. why would you try joins if you only have one table with three columns?   Something tells me you are leaving important details out of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find fruits that have multiple tastes for the same color:

```
select  fruit
from    fruit
group by
        fruit
,       color
having  count(distinct taste) > 1
```

To list all rows related to these fruits:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  count(*) over (partition by fruit, color) cnt
        ,       *
        from    fruits
        group by
                fruit
        ,       color
        ,       taste
        ) sub
where   cnt > 1
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0ad97/4/1)

Comment: Group by is not necessary on the second and I already posted the correct syntax

Comment: @paparazzo: the `group by` helps when there are multiple rows with the same fruit, color and taste.  Try it at the linked SQL Fiddle

Comment: I suspect if there are multiple OP would want to see then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` function

```
select * from (select *,
                    row_number() over (partition by fruit, taste order by fruit) Seq 
               from table t) t 
where Seq > 1;
```

By this you found Seq nos > 1 if fruit has duplicate taste and you can filter them & remove by using `subquery` with `delete` statment

```
delete t 
from  (select *,
           row_number() over (partition by fruit, taste order by fruit) Seq 
       from table t) t
where Seq > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a PK or unique constraint on fruit, color

```
select * 
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by fruit, color) as cnt 
      from table 
     ) t 
where t.cnt > 1 
order by fruit, color
```